# HTML Snippets that repeat in the Rails views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

I am using a bootstrapping framework, that has the following snippet, which I use a lot:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">...</div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

*(The snippet will be actually bigger, but I want to start small)*

So I thought I would build a partial and use it, something like this:

**Partial**

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading"><%= title %></div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <%= yield %>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Use example**

```
<%= render partial: "panel", locals: { title: "Hello" } do %>
    Testing
<% end %>
```

But this apparently is not working. I get the following error:

> 'nil' is not an ActiveModel-compatible object. It must implement :to_partial_path.

Am I doing something wrong here? Did I understood partials wrong?

Comment: how many times you want to iterate that partial?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. If what you are asking is how often I will use it. I might use it more than 50 times

Comment: Dbugger, can you show all the contents of the partial?

Comment: I have not developed the rest of the partial yet. What I have copied is the actual content of the partial, at the time of writing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for `yield` to work I think you need to use `render :layout` instead of/in addition to `:partial`:

```
<%= render layout: "panel", locals: { title: "Hello" } do %>
    Testing
<% end %>
```

Have a read of the [PartialRenderer](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/PartialRenderer.html) examples for more information

Comment: For some reason I had the feeling that `render layout:` was only meant to be used to define the main layout of the page, meaning the top level view. Your solution seems to work, even though it does not look too idiomatic. Thanks!

Comment: A layout is just a bit of surrounding HTML used for formatting. You can add a layout to any block of code in any template, and layouts can be as long/short as you need. The [PartialRenderer documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/PartialRenderer.html) has some great examples.